# Extract Text from URL

Tags: c#, url

the problem is I need to extract just text content of a given URL. 
I should insist that I just need the text content. there is many methods on the internet which return all content of a web page without any text separation.

I need the code in c# language.

thanks for any answer

Comment: Can you try and explain more clearly?

Comment: _"I need the code in c# language."_ Do you have PayPal?

Comment: the problem is how to clear a hypertext from html tags, images and other contents other than text by goal of generating the text of it?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML there is no such thing as "just text". Text you see on a webpage is rendered according to how the markup is defined.

You could manually strip all HTML tags between the `<body></body>` tags, then you'd have something like all text on the page. This will be error-prone, however.

Most solutions you'll find online will opt for a regular expression (something like `Regex.Replace(str, "<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);`), but if you use that you're likely to shoot yourself in the foot one day.

Comment: Yes, that regular expression looks set to blow up in your face as soon as you hit a page with, say, embedded JavaScript where one `<` condition is followed (in the HTML document) by a later `>` condition... (let alone `ALT` texts and similar). You probably didn't mean to `@` the string, btw.

Comment: You only need one `<` that doesn't belong to an HTML tag to screw it up, there's bound to be another `>` for closing an HTML tag (for example `<a href="...">`), after which the regex will consume everything in between and you won't get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Well You need to Use some Parsing Technique to get Text like , you can use Xpath, or Regular Expression for getting Text from giving Url's Html

Comment: Wow, a regular expression that correctly strips HTML from a random web page? Would you be willing to share that one?

Comment: Also, HTML is not XML, so XPath almost certainly will not help you. Take `<IMG>` or `<BR>` for example, which have no corresponding end tags.